# Prevent Android SeekBar of drawing multiple thumbs on progress change

Tags: android

I'm creating an overlay dialog for my appplication, this is how it looks:

[image: overlay dialog]

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ipTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/volumeSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="63"
        android:mirrorForRtl="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/portTv"
        style="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="63"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The code:

```
if (alertDialogLayout == null) {
            alertDialogLayout = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.volume_dialog, null);    

            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

            WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = new LayoutParams();
            wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
            wmlp.width = dm.widthPixels / 5;
            wmlp.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            wmlp.y += 10;
            wmlp.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
            wmlp.flags = LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;
            wm.addView(alertDialogLayout, wmlp);
        }

        if (volumeBar == null) {
            volumeBar = (SeekBar) alertDialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.volumeSeekBar);
            volumeBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
//Do some stuff
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
            });
        }
```

Why the SeekBar adds more than one thumb? As more I drag it, more thumbs appear, until it's completely full with them. I've checked - `OnSeekBarChangeListener` is assigned only once. Is there any errors in the code/layout, which I'm missing and causing such strange visual behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.informaticscentre.co.uk/blog/implementing-a-seekbar-with-stepped-intervals-in-android

Comment: I'm sorry, you didn't understood my question. I'm NOT trying to achieve this behaviour, I'm trying to get rid of this on default SeekBar. I don't understand, why it doesn't work like normal.

Comment: @insomnium_ what is the stuff you doing when progress changed ?[`onProgressChanged()`]

Comment: Right now - nothing, but the fantom thumbs still appear.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not multiple thumbs, but multiple `SeekBars`, multiple `alertDialogLayout` and each one has a `SeekBar`, or multiple objects created each one creates an `alertDialogLayout`, So, at first make sure that you initiate the `alertDialogLayout` only once and also that you initiate the `SeekBar` only once, also make sure that you are not (some how) initiate an `alertDialogLayout` or a `SeekBar` every **SeekBar progress change**, and to momentarily test all of that, just change the `alertDialogLayout` and the `SeekBar` declaration to `static` and look if that strange behaviour disappears.

Comment: The `SeekBar` and `alertDialogLayout` are `private static` from the beginning. I've just tried to REMOVE `static` keyword - no changes.

Comment: @insomnium_ well, but there isn't a way to have such number of thumbs, and my opinion is the only way to have such behavior is multiple seekbars or multiple something that creates a seekbar.

Comment: @insomnium_ and a good way to discover what happens, override the `onProgressChanged()` method[just print any thing in console] to make sure it they are resulted from seeking or not.

Comment: I've just did that - added progress print to console. Nothing suspicious, it just prints out progress, no sudden duplicates in console log or something else.